# UNC Path within a programs command line batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, unc

I am using a great little program [text2folders](http://skwire.dcmembers.com/wb/pages/software/text-2-folders.php) and I have been able to make it run as a right click context menu in windows 10. I have it working perfect for drives with drive letters but it is failing when I using it on UNC path shares.  I know I am close but struggling to fix this last bit for UNC paths.

When I run on a UNC share it is adding <> around the path and causing the program to fail. [image: a sample of the error I am seeing]

I need ideas how to either remove the <> or stop them from being created in the first place. Here is my registry entry and my batch file for the command line.
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

My Registry entry

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\cadastralfolders]
@="Create Cadastral Folders"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\cadastralfolders\command]
@="cmd.exe /s /k pushd \"%V\\\"&call \"\\\\server2\\data structured\\PROJECTS\\CADASTRAL NETWORK\\Text2Folders\\cadastralfolders.bat\" \"%V\" \"exit\""
```

My batch

```
@echo off
start "" "\\SERVER2\Data Structured\PROJECTS\CADASTRAL NETWORK\Text2Folders\Text2Folders.exe" "%cd%" "\\SERVER2\Data Structured\PROJECTS\CADASTRAL NETWORK\Text2Folders\cadastral folder stucture.txt" -q 
exit
```